# How do I do Batch Geocoding and get latitude and longitude for multiple intersections

Tags: gis, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Essentially I have an extensive list of different intersections. My end goal is to create points and lines for Intersection A to Intersection B for each order I have which contains a starting point and ending point. The problems I am running into are as followed:

1). Using API I have only found a way to get lat and long by entering each individual intersection and putting the output in an excel file. But, this will take way too long as I have multiple different intersections. I am looking for a different way to get the lat and long points for all of these maybe something through R or Python but everything I have read uses addresses.
2.) Once I get these lat and long points I want to put this on a map as points and connect the points to make lines for each of the start and end points on an order?

Any kind of help to push me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: This is pretty broad, can you post some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1):

This is only one of what I'm sure is many answers.  Whether or not an API allows intersection geocoding is dependent on the vendor.  For instance, the MapQuest API allows you to geocode intersections and will return the geocode type in the response: https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/samples/geocoding/v1/address/

I did a simple test with this intersections and the first result was an intersection: https://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=KEY&inFormat=kvp&outFormat=json&location=12th+ave+and+speer+blvd%2C+Denver%2C+CO&thumbMaps=false

The first link I provided is a testing console so you can see if it will suit your needs.  You would need to filter out your responses to only include results with the type `"geocodeQuality": "INTERSECTION"`

They support batch geocodes, but I would use the single location geocoder as a test.